# Trouble inserting a CSS Grid into a flexbox layout

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to insert a CSS grid layout within a flexbox layout so that 3 "grids" flex across a page row then the next three "grids" fill another row etc. At the moment all the "grids" line up in the centre of the page in one column when they should flex into rows of three abreast.

php code for itinery list page

```
<?php
include("assets/includes/header.inc.php");
include("config.php");
include("classes/ItineryResultsProvider.php");

if(isset($_GET['location'])) {
    $location = $_GET['location'];
}
else {
    exit("You must select an itinery location");
}
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
?>
<body>
<section class="PageWrapper">

    <section class='PageContentContainer'>
    
        <?php

        $resultsProvider = new ItineryListProvider($conn);
        $pageSize = 18;
        $numResults = $resultsProvider->getNumResultsItineryList($location);

        $removeUnderscoreLocation = str_replace('_', ' ', $location);

        echo "<div class='PageContentListCount'>

        <h2>This page shows a list of $numResults suggested itineries for $removeUnderscoreLocation.</h2>

        </div>";

        echo $resultsProvider->getResultsItineryList($page, $pageSize, $location)

        ?>
        
        <div class="PaginationGridContainer">

            <div class="PaginationGridLogo">
                <img src="assets/logos/Page_Numbering.png">
            </div>
            <div class="PaginationGridNumbering">


            <?php

            $pagesToShow = 10;
            $numPages = ceil($numResults / $pageSize);
            $pagesLeft = min($pagesToShow, $numPages);

            $currentPage = $page - floor($pagesToShow / 2);

            if($currentPage < 1) {
                $currentPage = 1;
            }

            if($currentPage + $pagesLeft > $numPages + 1) {
                $currentPage = $numPages + 1 - $pagesLeft;
            }

            while($pagesLeft != 0 && $currentPage <= $numPages) {

                if($currentPage == $page) {
                    echo "<div class='PageNumberContainer'>
                            <span class='PageNumber'>$currentPage</span>
                        </div>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<div class='PageNumberContainer'>
                            <a href='ItineryList.php?location=$location&page=$currentPage'>
                                <span class='PageNumber'>$currentPage</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>";
                }

                $currentPage++;
                $pagesLeft--;

            }

            ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section> 
        

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

php code for itinery list page classes

```
<?php
class ItineryListProvider {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getNumResultsItineryList($location) {

        $query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total
                                        FROM bth_itn_tbl WHERE ITN_STATUS='1'
                                        AND ITN_LOCATION LIKE :location");
        
        
        $searchTerm = $location;
        $query->bindParam(":location", $searchTerm);                            
        $query->execute();

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row["total"];

    }


    public function getResultsItineryList($page, $pageSize, $location) {

        $fromLimit = ($page - 1) * $pageSize;

        $query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                                        FROM bth_itn_tbl WHERE ITN_STATUS='1'
                                        AND ITN_LOCATION LIKE :location
                                        ORDER BY ITN_CLICK_COUNT DESC
                                        LIMIT :fromLimit, :pageSize");

        $searchTerm = $location;
        $query->bindParam(":location", $searchTerm);
        $query->bindParam(":fromLimit", $fromLimit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(":pageSize", $pageSize, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();


        $resultsItineryList = "<div>";


        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row["ITN_KEY"];
            $itnImg = $row["ITN_IMG_PATH"];
            $title = $row["ITN_TITLE"];
            
            
            
            $resultsItineryList .= "<div class='ItineryListFlexbox'>

                                    <div class='ItineryListGrid'>

                                    <a class='IntineryListGridImage'>
                                            <img src='$itnImg' height='169' width='225'>
                                    </a>

                                    <a class='ItineryListGridTitle'>$title</a>

                                    </div>

                                    </div>";
        }


        $resultsItineryList .= "</div>";

        return $resultsItineryList;
    }

    

}
?>
```

CSS code. Note that the PageWrapper and PageContentContainer is generic for all pages and works fine. The issue is with the ItineryListGrid which is supposed to flex within ItineryListFlexbox. At the moment it is a vertical centred column within the PageContentContainer

```
.PageWrapper {
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.PageContentContainer {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 710px;
  border: 2px solid #111;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px #888888;
}
.PageContentListCount h2 {
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #111;
  justify-content: left;
}
.PageContentContainer h3 {
  margin: 0 0 15px 10px;
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #111;
}
.AdvertisingContainer {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 15px 5px 5px;
  width: 320px;
  border: 2px solid #111;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px #888888;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;
}
.ItineryListFlexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
}
.ItineryListGrid {
  margin: 10px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 225px;
  grid-template-rows: 169px 50px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "IntineryListGridImage"
  "ItineryListGridTitle";
 }
.IntineryListGridImage {
  grid-area: IntineryListGridImage;
}
.ItineryListGridTitle {
  grid-area: ItineryListGridTitle;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
}
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but I am currently working on a project that can generates the new CSS Grid, maybe it can help check it out at github [essentials](https://github.com/jacobxperez/essentials). All you need is to set the numbers of columns on the [varables.less](https://github.com/jacobxperez/essentials/blob/master/css/variables.less) file then compile [style.less](https://github.com/jacobxperez/essentials/blob/master/css/style.less) using [less](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: I have added more code to help identify the issue